# Update State to Make Converting Plan to module easier?

Tags: terraform

Can I modify state to convince terraform to only report actual changes and not scope changes?

**Goal**

Easily verify conversion of plan to module by reducing the delta.

**Process**

1. Create a module from a plan
2. Modify plan to use module passing all its required variables
3. Run `terraform plan` and expect NO changes

**spoiler**: all items in the plan get destroyed and recreated as the shift in scope.

```
- myplan.aws_autoscaling_group.foo
+ module.mymodule.aws_autoscaling_group.foo
```

**Possible Solution**

If I could update state as if I ran an apply without changing infrastructure, then I could run a plan and see just the difference between the actual infrastructure and my plan with not scope changes.

```
terraform state list
for each item
     terraform state mv <oldval> module.mymodule.<oldval>
```

This works, but I'm moving from a plan that uses another module to a module that uses a module and mv on a module doesn't seem to work.

```
terraform state mv module.ecs_cluster module.mymodule.ecs_cluster

Error moving state: Unexpected value for InstanceType field: "ecs_cluster"

Please ensure your addresses and state paths are valid. No
state was persisted. Your existing states are untouched.
```

Comment: What makes you say that you can't move a resource from one module to another? I'm pretty sure I've done it before including with nested modules.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR . hmm, ok I updated the question to include the mv.  So, do I mv the entire module at once or field by field? If I mv `terraform state mv module.ecs_cluster module.mymodule` then it doesn't seem to nest but just disappear.  I'm on 0.8.8 , maybe I'll try with 011.7 to see

Comment: it seems I can hand edit the file provided I increment the serial.  Strange that mv doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You have to move each resource one by one but you can iterate through them as you described.

Comment: The child module which becomes a grand child module is the tricky part.  I can't move the the element of it as the destination doesn't exist.